# How do I get a count for each unique value in a dataframe column, even if I don't know what the unique values are?

Tags: r, dataframe

Basically, I'd like to identify the unique values in an R dataframe column and get a count of each one, with the ultimate goal of ranking them largest count to smallest. Any ideas how I can go about doing this?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I would suggest adding a sample of the data and code which will make it easier for users to provide a useful answer

Answer (score 1):

The base R function is `table`

```
table(df$column)
```

A reproducible example using `mtcars`

```
> data(mtcars)
> table(mtcars$cyl)
 4  6  8 
11  7 14 
> sort(table(mtcars$cyl),decreasing=TRUE) 
 8  4  6 
14 11  7
```

Comment: Always a pleasure to see base R solution (reminders).

Answer (score 0):

One option is `add_count` that creates a column with frequency count and then use that to `order` the rows

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     add_count(col1) %>%
     arrange(desc(n))
```

If we need only the summarised values, use `count`

```
df1 %>%
    count(col1) %>%
    arrange(desc(n))
```

---

A reproducible example using `mtcars`

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars %>% 
    add_count(vs) %>%
    arrange(desc(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- as.data.frame(table(df$colname)) %>%
  arrange(desc(Var1))
```